# How can I resize a "link to file" image in RTF document?

Tags: image, ms-word, rtf

My program creates RTF files with links to image files (not embedded). I can't figure out how to override the size of the images.

I generate the following RTF:

```
{\field
    {   \*\fldinst
        {   INCLUDEPICTURE "C:\\\\dir\\\\image.jpg" MERGEFORMAT \\d \\w2786 \\h2409 \\pm1 \\px8177 \\py17 \\pw0}
    }
}
```

When I load the document into MS Word, Word seems to completely ignore the width/height info, reverting to the actual size of the image.

I tried to figure out how Word does it by creating a document, inserting a link to an image, re-sizing the image and saving the document as RTF.

When I close & re-open the document, the image is back to its original size. There is no sizing information in the RTF file that is created by Word.

I cannot find a description of \d, \w, \h, \pm etc. in the RTF specification. (I found these at http://www.wpcubed.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5498).

How can I change the size of the image?

Note: the program also offers the option of embedding the image, so that's not a solution. Asking the user to externally re-size the image is also not an option.

Comment: FWIW the switches you mention are not recognised by Word - I think they are probably only recognised by the product discussed in the reference you provide. Field switches are just pieces of text in the field instruction (fldinst) as far as RTF is concerned, so the RTF spec does not need to document them. I *believe* that a way you can preserve size is to include the shape RTF that Word generates when you save a file with an INCLUDEPICTURE (there is a fldrslt, with a shppict, with  a blipuid, etc. etc.) , but you would have to work out exactly what needs to be in there and how to encode the pic

Comment: 'shppict' belongs to the '\pict' group, where the data is embedded in the file. Perhaps the fact that even Word cannot store the size data of a linked image file, in an RTF, is an indication that this is simply not supported. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: yes, I believe you need the shppict to retain the image size info. What I am less sure about is what happens when you modify the image path/file name and re-execute the INCLUDEPICTURE field - does the result  take on the size characteristics of the existing image or the new image? Probably the only other way to do this is to insert an image container whose size you can fix (not sure a textbox will let you do that but perhaps an old-style frame will) and put your INCLUDEPICTURE in there. But then you have to work out the correct RTF for a floating object.

Comment: I created a text box and inserted a photo. I closed & re-opened the RTF file, and Word crashed. Repeatedly. Then I changed the photo position from "In line with test" to "Square". It saved the image size, but it embedded the photo instead of linking. I think this wasn't meant to be  :o( How does one create a frame?

Comment: Frames are the deprecated predecessors of textboxes. I some versions of Word there is a right-click option to convert a textbox to a frame, possibly via an intermediate menu. But in Word 2010 (for example) you can go into File->Options->Quick Access Toolbar, choose All Commands, locate Insert Horizontal Frame add it tot he QAT, then click it in the QAT.